# C programming how do i use if statement properly with strings for the below code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char apple[]="Apple";
    char banana[]="Banana";
    char orange[]="Orange";

    printf("Choose one of the below options\n\n");
    printf("Which fruit do you like the most: Apple, Banana, Orange\n\n");
    scanf("%s",&apple,&banana,&orange);
    if("%s", apple)
    {
        printf("You chose Apple.\n");
    }
    if("%s",banana)
    {
        printf("You chose banana.\n");
    }
}
```

// I want the code to simply print on screen the choice i chose. But when i run the code it prints both Apple and Banana. If i type Apple i do not want it to print Banana. Do i need to use else statement with this? or what else am i missing? Thank you i am very new to c programming.

Comment: Please format your question correctly..

Comment: So many things wrong here. "I am very new" does not mean you are automatically excused from learning the very basics first.

Comment: And what should a person do if it is the very basics that a person needs help with? Does the person has no right to seek help until the basics are solid?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use strcmp() to compare between strings. see the following code.

strcmp() will return 0 if the contents of both strings are equal.

strcmp() will return <0 if the first character that does not match has a lower value in ptr1 than in ptr2.

strcmp() will return >0 if the first character that does not match has a greater value in ptr1 than in ptr2.

[reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char apple[]="Apple";
    char banana[]="Banana";
    char orange[]="Orange";
    char input[100];

    printf("Choose one of the below options\n\n");
    printf("Which fruit do you like the most: Apple, Banana, Orange\n\n");
    scanf("%s",input);
    if(strcmp(input,apple)==0)
    {
        printf("You chose Apple.\n");
    }
    if(strcmp(input,banana)==0)
    {
        printf("You chose banana.\n");
    }
    if(strcmp(input,orange)==0)
    {
        printf("You chose orange.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, the strcmp is very new to me but i will study more into it.

Comment: You can check out the reference ! :)